# How do I view the user registration form (as a page/node) while signed in as Admin.

Tags: forms, users

I can see the user registration form fields at Administration/Configuration People/Account Settings/Manage Display/User Account, however I cannot find a way to display this information as it would appear on a Drupal page/node. What am I missing?

Hank

Answer (score 0):

The **user/register** path in Drupal only displays a form for *anonymous users*. If you wish to view it as you're changing form elements, open up an anonymous tab (e.g. Igcognito in Chrome, Private Browsing in Safari, etc.) and reload the page as you make updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the registration form on:

> admin/people/create